# How to disable Remote Desktop Connection from my Windows?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

We have a PC with Windows 8.1. I don't want anyone to be able to use a Remote Desktop Connection from this computer.

In other words: I want disable this possibility on this PC.

Comment: "*from*"? That is you want to prevent connections to another computers from this Windows 8.1 machine? Not the connections from other computers to this particular one, right?

Comment: accurately , I want prevent connection to other computers.

Answer (score 2):

The Remote Desktop Connection client is an executable file `C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe`.

To prevent it from running you can:

- delete the file (but Windows update might put the file back)
- set up the AppLocker policy to prevent users from executing the file

  A visual tutorial on setting the policy is available on Microsoft TechNet wiki [How to configure AppLocker Group Policy to prevent software from running](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5211.how-to-configure-applocker-group-policy-to-prevent-software-from-running.aspx).
- block the outgoing connections to TCP port 3389

Answer (score 1):

You can find a file `%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe` and go to its `Properties`. Click `Advanced` button on the `Security` tab. Now you can add rule for specific users/groups/identities to DENY (when you click 'add' you can find 'Type' on top of a window) permissions to 'Read & execute'.